# Как подключить модуль с математическими функциями?

Tags: delphi

Уважаемые специалисты!
Подскажите, пожалуйста. Мне необходимо в `delphi` (создание приложений `Win32`) использовать функцию `arcsin`, но для этого нужен модуль `math`, которого у меня нет. Видел на одном из форумов, что можно использовать библиотеку от `Windows` с математическими формулами,  но предложенный там способ почему-то не работает. Подскажите, как это можно сделать или существует иное решение проблемы.
Заранее благодарен всем ответам. С уважением, Марат.

Comment: То есть вы хотите сказать если написать в программе `uses Math`, она у вас не компилируется?

Comment: Да, именно так, в моей версии модуля `math` нет.

Comment: А какая у вас версия, если не секрет?

Comment: Это по меньшей мере крайне странно. math есть всегда. От имени администратора пробовали запускать?

Comment: Я нашел такой пост:
В Delphi модуль Math поставляется только с Enterprise-версией программы. 
Решением является заимствование модуля Math из пиратской Enterpise-версии, но это, воровство. Самому же создавать матеатическую библитеку с нуля - занятие неблагодарное.
Не работая плотно на MSVC я был не в курсе наличия библиотеки crtdll.dll в Windows (насколько мне удалось выяснить, она является частью операционной системы, по крайней мере ставится вместе с Win 9x/NT/2000. Можно решить указанную проблему,воспользовавшись готовым решением - объявить все необходые функции из math.h в своей программе.

Comment: Там дальше был пример:
Пример с atan2:

function atan2(x, y: Double): Double; stdcall;
  external 'crtdll.dll' name 'atan2'; 

Я переделал его под arcsin, приложение компилировалось, но при запуске выдает: "Точка входа в процедуру arcsin не найдена в библиотеке DLL crtdll.dll"

Comment: арксинус у них в библиотеке называется `asin()`, а не `arcsin`

Comment: Завелось!!! большое спасибо.
P.S. Во я тупой такую ерунду и не догадался.

Answer (score 1):

А вообще разово можно обойтись и этим:

```
function ArcSin(const X : Single) : Single; 
asm
  fld1
  fld    X
  fst    st(2)
  fmul   st(0), st(0)
  fsubp
  fsqrt
  fpatan
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

А зачем писать всю математическую библиотеку, если нужен только арксинус?
Достаточно вспомнить школьный курс математики (или посмотреть [здесь](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8))

```
fuction arcsin( const Number : Extended ) : Extended;
begin
  result := arctan(Number/(sqrt(1-sqr(Number))));
end;
```

И всех делов.
А можно подсмотреть [тут](http://www.hackchina.com/en/r/24750/VectorGeometry.pas__html).

Comment: Влазить в математику алгоритма???
А также, уточните, о каких четвертях разговор? Каких знаков? Может, все-таки стоит почитать хотя бы на википедии базовые формулы?

Comment: Я имел ввиду четверти функций sin и tg, коментарий я удалил так как нашел в нем огромную ошибку, и не только в нем но и во всем своем алгоритме. Спасибо что навели меня на эту мысль!!!

Comment: Фух пронесло в алгоритме ошибки нет.
А тригонометрию надо вспоминать, с этим я с вами согласен.